# Autocomplete for class names in JS object values where key is named "className"

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, styled-components, tailwind-css

I would like to use Styled Components with Tailwind CSS (utility CSS framework). So take into account this simple component :

```
const Card = styled.div.attrs({
  className: "bg-white mx-auto max-w-sm shadow-lg rounded-lg",
})``;
```

I've set Tailwind classes using `attrs` but now I don't have autocomplete for class names in that object passed to `attrs`. Is there a way to make this work in VSCode or WebStorm?